# Android: using Calendar to compare 2 dates

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm trying to compare two instances of calendar but something does not work as I expect it. My code goes as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar past = Calendar.getInstance();
        past.set(2014,2,30);
        Log.d("ppp",String.valueOf(now.after(past)) +" \n Past: " + past.toString() +" \n  Now: "+ now.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I would expect the above code to return true, but looking at the logCat this is what I get:

```
false 
Past: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1396174280322,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Europe/Amsterdam,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=14,WEEK_OF_MONTH=6,DAY_OF_MONTH=30,DAY_OF_YEAR=89,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=1,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=12,MINUTE=11,SECOND=20,MILLISECOND=322,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000] 
Now: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1394622680322,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Europe/Amsterdam,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=11,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=12,DAY_OF_YEAR=71,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=12,MINUTE=11,SECOND=20,MILLISECOND=322,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

In particular I don't understand why for example MONTH is the same for both objects (why isn't the current one 3?) while DAY_OF_YEAR is actually higher in the past Calendar than in the current one.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Works as intended. Read the docs.

Android java.util.Calendar looks to behave in a similar way to the standard Java version.
[Java docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

> Any field values set in a Calendar will not be interpreted until it
>   needs to calculate its time value (milliseconds from the Epoch) or
>   values of the calendar fields. Calling the get, getTimeInMillis,
>   getTime, add and roll involves such calculation.

[Android docs say](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html):

> set(f, value) changes field f to value. In addition, it sets an
>   internal member variable to indicate that field f has been changed.
>   Although field f is changed immediately, the calendar's milliseconds
>   is not recomputed until the next call to get(), getTime(), or
>   getTimeInMillis() is made. Thus, multiple calls to set() do not
>   trigger multiple, unnecessary computations.

Comment: Ok so why is the month in the current calendar set to 2? And why is the WEEK_OF_YEAR value different?

Comment: Because months are zero-indexed. 0=January ... 2=March